# How to get the value of the checkbox present in the row on the click of that row

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Need to get the value of the checkbox to pass it to a function when I click on the row of a webgrid.

Tried this but it is giving the value of the first checkbox in the webgrid every time.

```
$(".Grid").find('tbody tr').on('dblclick', function () {
                var sID = $('.radar-checkbox').val();
                });
```

IT should get the CheckBox value of that selected row.

Comment: Are you looking for the value of the checkbox that receives the `dblclick` event? Can you post an example of the HTML? **NOTE** If there are multiple ".radar-checkbox" in that `<tr>`, jQuery will only ever return the `.val()` of the _first_ one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the checkbox inside the clicked row:

```
$(".Grid").find('tbody tr').on('dblclick', function () {
    var sID = $(this).find('.radar-checkbox').val();
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".Grid").find('tbody tr').on('dblclick', function () {
      var sID = $(this).find('.radar-checkbox :selected').val();
// ... });
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing some more context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.